# Haskell: f n that returns list of lists of n elements from [1..n]

Tags: algorithm, haskell

I need a function `f :: (Integral n) => n -> [[n]]`.

The returned list should contain all lists of length `n` where all elements originate from `[1..n]`.

**Example:**

```
f 2 = [[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2]]
```

---

This is an easy problem for constant `n`s:

```
f2 = [[a, b] | a <- [1..2], b <- [1..2]]
f3 = [[a, b, c] | a <- [1..3], b <- [1..3], c <- [1..3]]
f4 = [[a, b, c, d] | a <- [1..4], b <- [1..4], c <- [1..4], d <- [1..4]]
```

Comment: Any attempt from your side?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You can see my attempt for constant `n`s, but I have no idea how to make this generic.

Comment: I guess it's a fairly basic question, but I don't know much about Haskell.

Comment: Hint: use recursion

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yeah, I assumed that recursion is needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

one solution can be

```
f n = sequence . replicate n $ [1..n]
```

Note that `f 10` will have 10^10 elements

Comment: Oh, I didn't expect it to be that simple - Thank you!

Comment: And you can use `enumFromTo` to avoid duplicating the reference to `n`, leading to a point-free version `f = sequence . (replicate <*> enumFromTo 1)`.

Answer (score 6):

Another method could be:

```
Prelude> import Control.Monad
Prelude Control.Monad> f n = replicateM n [1..n]
Prelude Control.Monad> f 2
[[1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[2,2]]
```

Comment: from @chepner's comment, in pointfree from  `replicateM <*> (enumFromTo 1)`

Answer (score 0):

A solution with the great `combinat` library:

```
Math.Combinat.Sets> combine 3 [1 .. 3]
[[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,2,2],[1,2,3],[1,3,3],[2,2,2],[2,2,3],[2,3,3],[3,3,3]]
```